# Angular scope issues with route resolve pattern

Tags: angularjs

I'm attempting to use this route resolve pattern, while having the ability to change a variable on my controller scope. Is there a way of doing this?

```
app.config(function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when("/", {
        templateUrl:"views/home.html",
        controller: "appCtrl",
        resolve: {
            loadSite: appCtrl.loadSite
        }
  });
});

var appCtrl = app.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.hidePoster = false; // default

    /*
    $scope.hidePoster = true; // worked fine when I applied it here
    $scope.$apply();
    */

}]);

appCtrl.loadSite = function () {
    $scope.hidePoster = true; // $scope is not defined
    $scope.$apply();
}
```

Comment: there is no `$scope` available outside of a controller and resolve is not part of one. Not really clear what you are trying to accomplish but you likely want to look at using a service to store whatever `hidePoster` is used for

Comment: Would I then run the service such as:

`resolve: { loadSite.run // my service }`

Comment: Is appCtrl a part of the controller? Does the function object create it's own scope?